Need to Implement Function calling for Mistral 7b-instruct v.02 model in Sagemaker
I trying to add function calling in my chatbot code to actually fetch the tools if the user query is related to the tool. I was trying based on the internet format but i don't know where the error is. The function calling is dosen't happens when i run the program.
I have my prompt text file(test.txt) and adding you the function calling and tool configuration, please help me to fix this which i been trying for more than 2 days.
Prompt File:
You are Eva, an AI Assistant from Joy Internal Medicine Clinic. During the conversation, based on the patient's input, you can book an appointment by checking the available slots using the 'available_slots' tool. 
Keep the conversation short.
The Clinic working hours are 8 AM to 5 PM daily, but they are closed on Sundays. You should FOLLOW the GUIDELINES strictly.

Always use the 'available_slots' tool to answer patient queries about available appointment slots.
Always use the 'reschedule_appointment' tool if the patient wants to reschedule an appointment.

### GUIDELINES:
 - DO NOT MAKE UP appointment slots if it is not in 'available_slots' tool.
 - Be sure to be kind, funny, witty, and empathetic.
 - Keep all your responses short and simple. Use casual language, phrases like "umm", "Well", and "I mean" are preferred.
 - This is a voice conversation, so keep your responses short, like in a real conversation.
 - Don't ramble for too long.
 - NEVER SUGGEST RESCHEDULING THE APPOINTMENT UNLESS THE PATIENT ASKS FOR RESCHEDULING.
 - If you can't understand the user's response, ask them to repeat.
 - DO NOT INTRODUCE YOURSELF MORE THAN ONCE IN THE CONVERSATION.
 - NEVER GENERATE RESPONSES ON BEHALF OF THE USER or PATIENT.
 - NEVER PRINT role and content.
 - GENERATE RESPONSES ONLY AS THE AI ASSISTANT AND NEVER AS THE PATIENT.
 - DO NOT ASK FOR A REASON IF THE PATIENT WANTS TO RESCHEDULE.
 - NEVER BOOK AN APPOINTMENT FOR A PARTICULAR TIME SLOT THAT IS ALREADY BOOKED, TO AVOID DOUBLE BOOKINGS.

Model Code:

> session = boto3.Session(
>     aws_access_key_id='',
>     aws_secret_access_key='',
>     region_name='' )
> 
> endpoint_name = "jumpstart-dft-mistral-7b-instruct" client =
> session.client('runtime.sagemaker')
> 
> 
> import functools names_to_functions = {
>     "read_availability_slots": functools.partial(read_availability_slots),
>     "rag_func": functools.partial(rag_func), }
> 
> def read_availability_slots():
>     print("Fetching availability slots...")
>     return {"slots": ["10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "1:00 PM", "5:00 AM"]}
> 
> tools = [
>     {
>         "name": "read_availability_slots",
>         "description": "Tool provides a list of available time slots for rescheduling appointments. Use this tool whenever the patient asks
> for available slots or wants to reschedule their appointment.",
>         "parameters": {
>             "type": "object",
>             "properties": {},
>             "required": [],
>         },
>     },
>     {
>         "name": "rag_func",
>         "description": "Answer patient question by retrieving relevant context from the document provided when patient asks about services
> offered by the clinic",
>         "parameters": {
>             "type": "object",
>             "properties": {
>                 "query": {
>                     "type": "string"
>                 }
>             },
>             "required": ["query"],
>         },
>     } ]
> 
> def query_endpoint(payload):
>     response = client.invoke_endpoint(
>         EndpointName=endpoint_name,
>         ContentType="application/json",
>         Body=json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8")
>     )
>     print("Response:",response)
>     model_predictions = json.loads(response["Body"].read())
> 
>     print("Model predictions:", model_predictions)
>         if isinstance(model_predictions, dict) and "tool_call" in model_predictions:
>         tool_call = model_predictions["tool_call"]
>         function_name = tool_call["name"]
>         function_args = tool_call.get("arguments", {})
> 
> def chatgpt_streamed(user_input, system_message, conversation_history,
> chat_log_filename, patient_name, appointment_date, appointment_time,
> tools):
> 
>     payload = {
>         "inputs": json.dumps([  # Serialize the inputs as a JSON string
>             {"role": "system", "content": system_message},
>             {"role": "user", "content": user_input},
>             # {"role": "assistant", "content": tool_response} if tool_response else None,
>         ]),
>         "parameters": {
>             "temperature": 0.5,
>             "max_new_tokens": 100,
>         },
>         "tools": tools,
>         "tool_choice": "auto"
>     }
> 
>     print("Payload sent to endpoint:", payload)  # Debugging line
>     response = query_endpoint(payload)


in the response i didnt get the tools response invoked. Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Please make sure your script above doesn't contain sensitive information (e.g, AWS API access keys, etc). Replace them with some dummy ones as needed.

Tool names in your prompt text and Python script are not matching ("available_slots" vs "read_availability_slots"), and it may be the cause of the issue.

i changed it later but it dosent give me the tool's reply..

is there a alternate method to invoke the model response = client.invoke_endpoint(

    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    ContentType="application/json",
    Body=json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8")
)


